# Phonegap windows phone 8 height content because of status bar

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have an issue with phonegap on windows phone 8. I want to have my app with the status bar, so I set:

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

in "config.xml" file but my app contains a footer and this footer are shift because of status bar.

Anybody can help to fix that ?

I already set the "meta viewport" but no change.

Answer (score 0):

try this .... set viewport in css file

```
@-ms-viewport{
width:device-width;
}
@-ms-viewport{
height:device-height;
}
```

http://trentwalton.com/2013/01/16/windows-phone-8-viewport-fix/

i developed one app using phonegap i used all solutions with status bar but this problem not solved. i had used "plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" version="0.1.4" plugin in config.xml file. this problem come only for windows so i hide status bar only for windows

```
<script>
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
        function startEvents() {
            StatusBar.hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```